# Use SED to insert newline at specific points in .html file that is only one very long line

Tags: bash, sed

This is a probably a duplicate but I can't find the right question...

I have a HTML file that is just one line long, and I'd like to insert a newline just after each `<div class=".+ uiBoxWhite noborder">`, where `.+` is a series of words which include special characters, and seem to be mostly random.

I thought that

```
sed -r 's/<div class=".+ uiBoxWhite noborder">/\n<div class="uiBoxWhite noborder">/g' old.html > new.html
```

would work, but it hasn't. Am I using the wrong wildcard? Or the wrong newline character?

Comment: You need to use the `-r` option to make it recognize the `+` operator.

Comment: @Barmar still not working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(<div class=")[^>]*(uiBoxWhite noborder">)/\n\1\2/g' oldFile  > newFile
```

Use `[^>]*` to restrict the remaining match within the current div.

Comment: Why the extra `>` in the replacement?

Comment: @Barmar Ooops! I forgot to remove all of the duplicated string.

Comment: Didn't read the question! Added back references so as to remove any special characters.